# WebStorm node configure balloon

Tags: node.js, webstorm

I am using WebStorm for a Node.js project, and I keep getting a warning balloon which is rather annoying, and I can't remove.

[image]

I have tried various things to remove, but have not been successful. What I have tried :

1. Files-> Settings-> Notifications -> I have disabled balloon notifications.
2. Files -> Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> Node.js and NPM

[image]

The configuration of the node modules does not work here either.

Anyone know how to remove the balloon?

Comment: What's your intention - just to remove the balloon or to configure libraries to get completion/types resolving? In the first case, just disable the 'Code assistance for Node.js Modules' inspection in Settings/editor/Inspections/javaScript/Node.js. In the latter case, agree to configure the library. Then either choose to download sources, or specify a path to them if you have downloaded the files already. You may find this blog post helpful (though the ui there is not up-to-date): http://blog.jetbrains.com/webide/2012/03/attaching-the-sources-of-node-js-core-modules/

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing, but it might be easier just to configure Node.js sources and add the libraries.

For Webstorm 9+:

Try selecting the 'Download from Internet' option instead Or determine what your source root directory should be (The default here is not correct for you).

Then, one or more of the following:

- A. Right-Click in the editor panel > Use Javascript Library > Node.js
  Globals
- B. Repeat A, but select Node.js Core Modules